# GridView is Shacking when i clicked my add Button

Tags: devexpress

When i Click add button My Grid is shacking.
the Button Id is="AddNewUnit"

If i click Add or Edit button my grid is shrinking and suddenly comeback to normal size for 1st time only.

If the page is refresh again same problem is doing.

I dont know how to solve the problem.

If any body know the problem. Let me know.

```
 <dx:ASPxCallbackPanel runat="server" ID="CallbackPanel" ClientInstanceName="CallbackPanel"  >
            <PanelCollection>
                <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent3" runat="server">
                    <dx:ASPxButton ID="AddNewUnit" ClientInstanceName="AddNewUnit" runat="server" Text="Add New" OnInit="AddNewUnit_Init" Image-Url="~/App_Themes/Images/add.png"
                        AutoPostBack="false">
                        <ClientSideEvents Click="function(s, e) {Grdview.AddNewRow(); }" />
                        <Image Url="~/App_Themes/Images/add.png"></Image>
                    </dx:ASPxButton>
                    <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblindex" ClientInstanceName="lblindex" runat="server" ClientVisible="false"></dx:ASPxLabel>
                    <dx:ASPxGridView ID="Grdview" ClientInstanceName="Grdview" runat="server" OnRowDeleting="Grdview_RowDeleting"
                        KeyFieldName="Id" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" OnRowInserting="Grdview_RowInserting"
                        OnRowUpdating="Grdview_RowUpdating" OnCellEditorInitialize="Grdview_CellEditorInitialize">
                        <ClientSideEvents CustomButtonClick="custombuttonclicks" />

                        <Columns>
                            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Edit" Width="6%" Name="EditButton" ShowEditButton="true">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>
                            <dx:GridViewCommandColumn ShowNewButton="true" Name="Delete" ShowEditButton="false" VisibleIndex="1" ButtonType="Image"
                                Width="6%" Caption="Delete">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                                <CustomButtons>
                                    <dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton ID="deluser">
                                        <Image ToolTip="Delete" Url="App_Themes/Images/delete.png" Width="22px" Height="22px" />
                                    </dx:GridViewCommandColumnCustomButton>
                                </CustomButtons>

                                <HeaderStyle Wrap="True" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                            </dx:GridViewCommandColumn>


                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Name" VisibleIndex="1" Width="14%" Settings-AutoFilterCondition="Contains"
                                Caption="Name">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                                <PropertiesTextEdit Width="250px">
                                    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="Text" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom">
                                        <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="Please enter the Name"></RequiredField>
                                    </ValidationSettings>
                                </PropertiesTextEdit>
                                <Settings AutoFilterCondition="Contains"></Settings>
                                <EditFormSettings VisibleIndex="0" Caption="Name" />
                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                            <dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="Age" Caption="Age" VisibleIndex="2" Width="10%" PropertiesTextEdit-MaxLength="50"
                                HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" CellStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" PropertiesTextEdit-ValidationSettings-RequiredField-ErrorText="Please enter the No. Of Beds"
                                Settings-AutoFilterCondition="Contains">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>

                                <PropertiesTextEdit Width="250px" ValidationSettings-ErrorDisplayMode="Text">
                                    <Style HorizontalAlign="Right">
                                                         </Style>
                                    <ValidationSettings ErrorTextPosition="Bottom">
                                        <RequiredField IsRequired="true" />

                                        <RegularExpression ValidationExpression="^\d*\.?\d*$" ErrorText="Age accepts only numbers" />
                                    </ValidationSettings>
                                </PropertiesTextEdit>
                                <EditFormSettings VisibleIndex="2" Caption="Age" />
                            </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>

                            <dx:GridViewDataMemoColumn FieldName="Country" Width="35%" VisibleIndex="3" Caption="Country"
                                Settings-AutoFilterCondition="Contains">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                                <PropertiesMemoEdit Height="50px" Width="250px">
                                    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="Text" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom">
                                        <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="Please enter the Country" />
                                    </ValidationSettings>
                                </PropertiesMemoEdit>
                                <EditFormSettings VisibleIndex="3" Caption="Country" />
                            </dx:GridViewDataMemoColumn>



                            <dx:GridViewDataMemoColumn FieldName="State" Width="35%" VisibleIndex="4" Caption="State"
                                Settings-AutoFilterCondition="Contains">
                                <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Font-Bold="True"></HeaderStyle>
                                <CellStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle"></CellStyle>
                                <PropertiesMemoEdit Height="50px" Width="250px">
                                    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="Text" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom">
                                        <RequiredField IsRequired="True" ErrorText="Please enter the State" />
                                    </ValidationSettings>
                                </PropertiesMemoEdit>
                                <EditFormSettings VisibleIndex="4" Caption="State" />
                            </dx:GridViewDataMemoColumn>
                        </Columns>

                        <SettingsCommandButton ApplyFilterButton-ButtonType="Button" ApplyFilterButton-Styles-FocusRectStyle-VerticalAlign="Middle">


                            <EditButton ButtonType="Image" Image-Height="24px" Image-Width="24px" Image-Url="App_Themes/Images/blueedit.png" Image-ToolTip="Edit">
                                <Image ToolTip="Edit" Height="24px" Width="24px" Url="App_Themes/Images/blueedit.png"></Image>
                            </EditButton>


                            <CancelButton ButtonType="Button" Styles-Style-VerticalAlign="Middle" Styles-Style-HorizontalAlign="Center" Image-ToolTip="Close Edit Form Without Saving Changes" Image-Width="60px">
                                <Image ToolTip="Close Edit Form Without Saving Changes" Width="60px"></Image>

                                <Styles>
                                    <Style HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></Style>
                                </Styles>
                            </CancelButton>


                            <ShowAdaptiveDetailButton ButtonType="Image"></ShowAdaptiveDetailButton>
                            <HideAdaptiveDetailButton ButtonType="Image"></HideAdaptiveDetailButton>
                            <ApplyFilterButton ButtonType="Button" RenderMode="Button">
                                <Styles>
                                    <FocusRectStyle VerticalAlign="Middle"></FocusRectStyle>
                                </Styles>
                            </ApplyFilterButton>


                            <UpdateButton ButtonType="Button" Styles-Style-VerticalAlign="Middle" Styles-Style-HorizontalAlign="Center" Image-ToolTip="Saving Changes." Image-Width="60px">
                                <Image ToolTip="Saving Changes." Width="60px"></Image>
                                <Styles>
                                    <Style HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle"></Style>
                                </Styles>
                            </UpdateButton>

                        </SettingsCommandButton>
                        <SettingsEditing EditFormColumnCount="2" Mode="PopupEditForm">
                    </SettingsEditing>
                    <SettingsPager Mode="ShowPager" AlwaysShowPager="true" PageSize="10" Position="Bottom">
                        <PageSizeItemSettings Visible="true" Caption="Units to display" Items="5, 10, 25, 50" />

                    </SettingsPager>
                    <Settings ShowFilterRow="true" ShowFilterRowMenu="true" VerticalScrollBarMode="Visible" VerticalScrollableHeight="432" />
                    <SettingsPopup>
                        <EditForm Width="760px" HorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" VerticalAlign="WindowCenter" Modal="true" />
                    </SettingsPopup>

                    <Settings ShowTitlePanel="false" />
                    <SettingsText Title="Add New" PopupEditFormCaption="Edit" />


                    </dx:ASPxGridView>
                </dx:PanelContent>

            </PanelCollection>
        </dx:ASPxCallbackPanel>

        <dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="PopupforCustDeletePopupSubmitConfirmation" runat="server" ShowPageScrollbarWhenModal="true" PopupHorizontalAlign="WindowCenter" PopupVerticalAlign="WindowCenter" ClientInstanceName="PopupforCustDeletePopupSubmitConfirmation" AllowDragging="false" AllowResize="false" HeaderText="Alert"
            EnableHotTrack="False" HeaderStyle-Font-Bold="true" CloseAction="CloseButton" Modal="True" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
            <ContentCollection>

                <dx:PopupControlContentControl ID="PopupControlContentControl1" runat="server">
                    <dx:ASPxPanel ID="ASPxPanel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="btOK">
                        <PanelCollection>
                            <dx:PanelContent ID="PanelContent2" runat="server">
                                <table style="width: 400px">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center">
                                            <dx:ASPxLabel ID="lblCustDeletePopupConfirmationMsg" ViewStateMode="Disabled" runat="server" Text="Are you sure you want to delete the Unit?">
                                            </dx:ASPxLabel>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </dx:PanelContent>
                        </PanelCollection>
                    </dx:ASPxPanel>
                    <br />
                    <br />

                    <table style="width: 100px; margin: auto;">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" style="width: 50px">
                                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnCustDeletePopupYes" runat="server" Text="Yes" Width="55px" AutoPostBack="false" ToolTip="Yes">
                                    <ClientSideEvents Click="CustDeletePopupYes_Click" />
                                </dx:ASPxButton>
                            </td>
                            <td align="center" style="width: 49px; padding-left: 5px;">
                                <dx:ASPxButton ID="btnCustDeletePopupNo" runat="server" Text="No" AutoPostBack="false" Width="55px" ToolTip="No">
                                    <ClientSideEvents Click="CustDeletePopupNo_Click" />
                                </dx:ASPxButton>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                </dx:PopupControlContentControl>
            </ContentCollection>
            <HeaderStyle>
                <Paddings PaddingRight="6px"></Paddings>
            </HeaderStyle>
            <SizeGripImage Height="16px" Width="16px">
            </SizeGripImage>
        </dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

[My Screenshot attached Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ndN6.png)

Comment: Can you show Javascript code except `Grdview.AddNewRow()`? Also you should open browser console window and inform in your question if you have errors related to `ReferenceError` or `TypeError`.

Comment: No error is coming while i click the button in console window.

Comment: The gridview is lightly shrinking and suddenly comes to normal. This happens only in first time.

Comment: Try `<Settings UseFixedTableLayout="True" />` on ASPxGridView control to set `table-layout: fixed` style. I see that you've total column width percentage larger than 100% due to 2 command columns that have same width (6% each, then 6 + 6 + 14 + 10 + 35 + 35 = 106%), please adjust them to 100% too.

Comment: Still i am facing same problem...

Comment: Could you provide how the grid shrinks in a little time by screencast or image? I still can't reproduce your problem in a new project in minimal context (providing basic add & edit functions), the ASPxGridView still in normal when the page (re)loads.

Comment: I attached my screeen shots give below of my code. marking area is shacking when i clicked add or edit button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <dx:ASPxFormLayout ID="ASPxFormLayout1" runat="server"></dx:ASPxFormLayout>
        <dx:ASPxPopupControl ID="ASPxPopupControl1" runat="server"></dx:ASPxPopupControl>
```

before aspxcallbackpanel paste it never shake.